# Create a list by the index of the column values meet the condition python

Tags: python, list

I have a dataframe with two columns ['A', 'B']. The columns are sorted already. I want to find a list of A values based on every first n times of 100 of column B and add min and max in the list. And n is fixed with 3 times.

> d={'A': [15,16, 17,19,20,21,25,26,27,28,29,30], 'B':
> [25,90,101,137,140,190,202,207,290,304,355,367]

> df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

The end result is to create a list=[15,17,25,28,30] based on another list of B values:[25, 101,202,304,367].

I previously set colA=[min(df.A)], and I'm trying to append the other three items based on the index of the colB list. And add the max column A value as the last item in the list colA.

So back to the other 3 items in colB, I'll need to do in the range(3) iteration. So when n=0, the first item is the first value that closed to (n+1)*100 but >(n+1)*100, same thing for the rest two values.

Comment: could you explain a bit more how you get the desired output? For example, how is `n` relevant when your output is length 5?

Comment: Why is `367` in the result list?

Comment: Thanks guys @enke. I changed the values in the list and updated the details. Hopefull that'll make more sense.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely, that's the max value from the column that I added to the list as the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you problem right, you can use `df.groupby`:

```py
out = df.groupby(df["B"] // 100)["A"].first().to_list() + [df["A"].max()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[15, 17, 25, 28, 30]
```